# Error using keras_model_sequential() in R

Tags: r, keras

Created this new post following a similar question asked at:[Error in keras_model_sequential for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778820/error-in-keras-model-sequential-for-r/48276470#48276470). There was no answer over there.

**Here is the error that i am getting**:

```
    Error in .Call(_reticulate_py_initialize, python, libpython, pythonhome, : Incorrect number of arguments (7), expecting 8 for _reticulate_py_initialize'
```

as can be seen from the error that i got and the error mentioned in the post above, the errors are very similar, but opposite.**Here are some other details that might be helpful in solving this error:**

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
keras_2.1.2.9001
tensorflow_1.4.3.9000
reticulate_1.4
```

**Following is the code that i used:**

```
    model = keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(units = 144,  input_shape = c(13170)) %>%
    layer_activation(activation = 'relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization()  %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 144) %>%
    layer_activation(activation = 'relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization()  %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 2) %>%
    layer_activation(activation = 'sigmoid')
```

Is the above code not sufficient enough to create the model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works for me `R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
keras_2.1.1.9002
tensorflow_1.4.1.9000
reticulate_1.3.1.9002 `

Comment: it should work..but for me it is giving this error..the advice i have got is to reinstall keras but it is still not working for me